# C# - VS2022: "global using" and code cleanup on save

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-cleanup

In VS2022 I turned on the very useful feature "Run Code Cleanup profile on Save".
With this option on, every unneeded `using` statement in code gets removed automatically on save.

Now I would like to create a .cs file that contains a bounch of `global using` statements and nothing else.
I think that having them in a separate, dedicated file helps keeping project clean.

However, since these `global using` statements are not used in the .cs file itself, they get removed every time I save the file.

Is there a way to skip cleanup in some circumstances? For example:

- For a specific file
- For global using statements
- When I save with a given keyboard/mouse shortcut (ex. by holding SHIFT or similar when clicking Save)

The first two options would be better because would work also if I run cleanup on the entire project.

**UPDATE**

I found out that this happens only in NET (8?) projects. `global using` directives in a NET Framework 4.6.2 project are not removed by code cleanup.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two options I see:

1. Exclude the file with global usings from cleanup in editor config. Add the following line to it (for example for file in the project root with name `GlobalUsings.cs`):

   ```
   [GlobalUsings.cs]
   generated_code = true
   ```

   [Docs for the feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/use-roslyn-analyzers?view=vs-2019#configure-generated-code), available starting with Visual Studio 2019 16.5.
2. Move the global usings to the csproj file (showing example for `System.Globalization` namespace):

   ```xml
   <ItemGroup>
       <Using Include="System.Globalization"/>
   </ItemGroup>
   ```

Comment: Great! I excluded my file from cleanup. Thank you!

Comment: UPDATE: I found out that this happens only in NET project. `global using` directives in a NET Framework 4.6.2 project are not removed by code cleanup.

Answer (score 0):

You can consider [configuring the cleanup actions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/code-styles-and-code-cleanup?view=vs-2022#code-cleanup-settings) you need to perform in the Code cleanup settings, such as Remove unnecessary Imports or usings.

[image]

You can also write your own [code-style rule options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/code-style-rule-options) and add in into your code cleanup configuration.